# find end of text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, string, html

i use a `XMLHttpRequest`. like this:

```
var httpVar = new XMLHttpRequest().open("GET", "s1.txt", false);
.....
var allText = httpVar.responseText;
```

now i have all `s1.txt` texts in a allText.
i want to Processing it.

```
for( i = 0 ; i < (?) ; i++)
{
    //Processing
}
```

where is the end of `s1.txt` file in `js/html5`.

Comment: `allText.length` will give you the length of the string. You can use that to find the end.

Comment: You can try split it by the *new line* delimiter(e.g. `\n` in regex) and read each line...

Answer (score 0):

check this function out, it reads file passed as parameter:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

            function readText(that){

                if(that.files && that.files[0]){
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {  
                        var output=e.target.result;

                        //process text to show only lines with "@":             
                        output=output.split("\n").filter(/./.test, /\@/).join("\n");

                        document.getElementById('main').innerHTML= output;
                    };//end onload()
                    reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
                }//end if html5 filelist support
            }
```

Comment: It was okay but a bit Pychydst and i think JavaScript does not have a lot of processing. its a browser side process.  
string processing method must be good implementation.